# Why is Matthew 17:21 missing from some Bibles?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, bible-translation, gospel-of-luke, gospel-of-mark, verse-identification

I see some questions have asked this about the NIV specifically - the list from the NIV specifically is as follows:

Matthew 17:21
Matthew 18:11
Matthew 23:14
Mark 7:16
Mark 9:44
Mark 9:46
Mark 11:26
Mark 15:28
Luke 17:36
John 5:3-4
Acts 8:37
Acts 15:34
Acts 24:6-8
Acts 28:29
Romans 16:24
1 John 5:7-8

These also appear to be missing from my RV, and ASV.

Were these omitted due to personal translator beliefs? If so, what are the content of these verses? Why is there no footnote?